# Getting wrong output for test cases

Tags: c

For the given question below i am getting a wrong answer for a large input (test case) how to fix these type of errors:

> Given a string S , find the total count of numbers present in the
>   digit.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line contains T , the number of test cases. The first line
>   of each and every testc ase will contain a integer N , the length of
>   the string . The second line of each and every test case will contain
>   a string S of length N.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each and every testcase , output the total count of numbers
>   present in the string.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> > 0 < T < 200
> >
> > 0 < N <10000
>
> **Sample input**
>
> ```
> 1
> 26
> sadw96aeafae4awdw2wd100awd
> ```
>
> **Sample output**
>
> ```
> 4
> ```

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main()
{
    char s[10000];
    int i,c=0,t;
    long long int l;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        clean_stdin();
        //  gets(s);
        scanf("%lld",&l);
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&s[i]);
        }

        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(isdigit(s[i])&&(isalpha(s[i+1])||s[i+1]=='\0'))
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the input is larger than `10000`, you have out of bound accesses.

Comment: no it just shows wrong answer

Comment: and my input is below 10000 but again the answer is wrong

Comment: Can input contain characters which are not alphanumeric ?

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? The sample test case [seems to work](http://ideone.com/QnCwaD).

Comment: Your program fails when the string ends with a number.

Comment: Related, you don't need an array for this anyway. Think about how you would *really* do this if it were handed to you on paper and you had to count the number of contiguous digit sequences per line.

Comment: Perhaps `"%lld "` to remove the newline after the number

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%lld", &l);` doesn't discard the newline *after* the number, so the character read by the first `scanf("%c", ...)` is the newline.

So if the number is exactly `9999`, it will read the *newline* and 9998 following characters, ignoring the 9999th.

The fix would be to add a space after the `%lld`: `scanf("%lld ", &l);`; this will discard the following whitespace.

---

Then again, you *don't* have to read these characters into a buffer - instead just use `getchar()` to read character at a time...